# Invalid property value?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give my search bar a background, using css. But chrome keeps giving the error "invalid property value". Which is weird because my navigation bar is the exact same code but doesn't give the error?
http://ispiked.net/tests/

Comment: Post the relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: No errors here. And also no background. And none seems to be specified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you've also specified "no-repeat" along with your background image. Alter your code to:

```
background: url(images/searchbar.png) no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do that is to use background-repeat property.

```
background-image: url('images/searchbar.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```