# invalid property value for css h1 tag background

Tags: css

Hi am getting invalid property values for css `h1` tag. here i want to display image inside `h1` tag from css class.

```
  header#header .logo {
    font: 0/0 a;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: transparent;
    background: url('../../Style Library/images/logo.png') no-repeat 0 0 transparent;   
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 62px;
    margin-top:-16px;
   }

    <a href="index.html">
       <h1 class="logo">Canara Robeco</h1>
    </a>
```

Comment: JFYI `h1` inside `a` is syntax error.

Comment: @alexeyten — Not since HTML5

Comment: It's allowed in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

`font: 0/0 a;` is not valid. The validator thinks that you are trying to set the font-weight to `0` rather then the font-size and line-height. I haven't figured out exactly why (I suspect the CSS parsing rules are not designed to let you set the font size to `0`).

The simplest work around to that would be to switch to using the long form properties instead of the `font` shorthand property.

The proper solution, since your image is a content image and not a background image, is to change your markup:

```
<a href="index.html">
   <h1 class="logo"><img src="/Style%20Library/images/logo.png" alt="Canara Robeco"></h1>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this out

```
 .logo {     //changge
    font: 0/0 a;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: transparent;
    background: url('../../Style Library/images/logo.png') no-repeat 0 0 transparent;   
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 62px;
    margin-top:-16px;
   }
```

Comment: The question says "am getting invalid property values for css", it doesn't say that the selector isn't matching the element.

Answer (score -1):

This can be because of your no-repeat property in the same line of your path of your logo image in your css. Try this:

```
background-image: url('../images/yourlogo.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421008/invalid-property-value).

Comment: Why would that help? The problem is that one of the property values is invalid. Using a different element isn't going to change that.

Comment: The error can be because of "no-repeat" in your css. try this: background-image: url('images/searchbar.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat; [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421008/invalid-property-value).