# Angular 5 background image will not show

Tags: angular-cli, angular5

I need help. I'm a complete beginner and I can't find solution anywhere, so sorry if it was already asked, but no matter what I tried I couldn't display background image on one page.

**What I want to do?**

Display the background image on home page.

**Notes:**

- I didn't have assets folder by default.
- Trying on Localhost:4200
- Going to Localhost:4200/assets/images/bg.jpg in browser displays the picture.
- If I put an online hosted image in url(), everything works.

---

Since there was no assets folder in my root, I created one in src folder.

**Structure:**

```
► node_modules
▼ src
   ▼ app
      ▼ components
         ▼ home
           home.component.html
           home.component.scss
           home.component.spec.ts
           home.component.ts
   ▼ assets
      ▼ images
         ▼ bg.jpg
```

---

**.angular-cli.json**

```
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "images",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

---

**home.component.scss**

```
.homeBg {
  background-image: url('../../../assets/images/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

---

Can someone please help me and tell me what I did wrong? I'm losing my mind for almost 3 hours trying to figure this out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the browser dev tools showing a 404 error for bg.jpg. If so, what's the requested url?

Comment: url('bg.507198febc2a9a98bcf6.jpg') - Invalid property value.

Comment: Hmm, yes. Seems that removing -image from background-image fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

Solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11421058/1116276).

> This is because you've also specified "no-repeat" along with your
>   background image. Alter your code to:
>
> ```
> background: url('../../../assets/images/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
> ```

Thanks [@Mike Lun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2394409/mike-lunn) for reminding me to check the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are working with Ionic you need to set the background property this way:

```
ion-content {
  --background: url("/assets/images/my-background.jpeg") no-repeat center center /
    cover;
}
```

That two dashes before the background worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.

I tried the solution above but it didn't work. It turns out that for me, I used a path like this: **'/static/resources/img/cancel.png'**. Changing it to **'../../assets/static/resources/img/cancel.png'** and then background back to background-image worked.